# iPad locked up due to iCloud Backup

Tags: ipad, icloud, backup

I have an issue with my iPad; it is locked up with the message that iCloud Backup has not been done in over 2 weeks.

It won't do anything or go any further even when all conditions for backup are met.

I cannot even turn it off because I cannot slide to power off and I get no response when touch "OK" button on iCloud Backup notification.

Any ideas on resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This works on the iPhone, so I can't see it not working on the iPad.

Hold the Power and Home buttons for approximately 10 seconds, the iDevice will shut down without having to slide the Power Off slider.